My Google Meet Addon presented in Google Meet won't follow the specified sidePanelUrl (or sidePanelUri)
I have written a Google Meet Addon in Vue 3/Typescript and serve the static page it from a public available and secure website. The URL of that website I have specified in the manifest.json in my Google Cloud project.
I also specified a logoURL in there and that is accessed and shown without a problem.
I tested the URL in my Chrome browser and it showed my page (ofcource telling me that it couldn't find the corresponding meeting).
Can anyone tell me why it does not access my Webserver?
My deployment.json:
   {
       "oauthScopes": ["https ://www.googleapis.com/auth/meet.addons.execute"],
       "addOns": {
             "common": {
                 "name": "My Meet addon v1.0.1",
                 "logoUrl": "https://home.xxx.nl:8000/favicon.ico"
             },
             "meet": {
                 "web": {
                      "sidePanelUri": "https://home.xxx.nl:8000/static/index.html",
                      "addOnOrigins": ["https://home.xxx.nl:8000"],
                      "sidePanelUrl": "https://home.xxx.nl:8000/static/index.html",
                      "darkModeLogoUrl": "https://home.xxx.nl:8000/favicon.ico"
                 }
             }
         }
     }

`
I expected to see in my webserver the GET HTTP requests from Google Meet.

Solved it. Both my server and browser were on the same (local) network. My browser could not access the FQDN, so Google Meet, started in my browser, could also not access the FQDN.
When I start Google Meet from a browser not connected to my LAN it all went fine.
